# Spring CSRF token life

Tags: java, spring-security, csrf-protection

I am implementing CSRF protection using Spring security as per the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf)

One question I have is: When this token will get invalidated by the Spring security?
Does the token gets invalidated for each request submit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the CSRF token is stored in the HTTP session and is generated on a per-session basis.  See [the official Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-timeouts) for more details.  Therefore, the default lifecycle of CSRF tokens is the session duration.

Like everything else in Spring Security, the storage and retrieval of CSRF tokens can be customized to suit individual needs.  The way to do that would involve creating an implementation for `CsrfTokenRepository`.  Custom implementations could change the token on a per request basis, store the token in a relational database, and so on.

Comment: Thank You. Since the default life span of the CSRF token is session, during this active session time a CSRF attacker link can attack my site right? [I mean, if I click on an attacker link while the session is active]

Comment: No, that is the scenario CSRF protection is for. If you happen to visit a malicious site while you have an active session on an important website, the malicious site cannot submit requests to the important website successfully. This is because the attacker will not have the CSRF token for the session and therefore forged requests will be rejected.