# Spring CSRF HTTP 403 forbidden error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I am migrating from struts to spring migration. Since I am working on latest spring version 4.3 and we decided to go with CSRF protection for our application. On our JSP page we have two tabs both clickable with http get methods to call spring controller. Each tab has multiple links and buttons. After the get call If I do any action on the page for example click of a button which does post call to controller. I am getting 403 forbidden with message "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?" .

In Firefox developer tools post call form data I could see _csrf with token being passed. Response header says x-frame-opitons: Deny.  I am suspecting the previous call HTTP GET which is on selecting the tab causing the issue. Do we need to pass csrf token for http GET methods as well ? any help ?

Comment: You might need to share some code because it's not very clear what you're asking. Firstly, no, you certainly don't need to send the CSRF token with a GET request, but when the GET request is processed by the controller, a new CSRF token will be generated, which is what Spring Security will be expecting to receive in the following POST. In the page that's displayed after the GET, do you still see a CSRF token, and is it updated? You should be seeing different values for the CSRF token in your browser before and after the GET.

Comment: I am getting the same csrf token after the GET call.  Actually I am not writing any new code to read from response.  All I am using is spring mvc <form:form> tag or <input hidden ...  />.  As per spring documentation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866529/spring-csrf-token-life  default csrf token lifetime is session based. I will try to add some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said I was working on migration project, for every call existing code they are cleaning session attributes in one of utility method. Though I am sending token in each request because of session cleaning in utility method my token is being compared with null value. Hence it was throwing error "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired".

Now it is resolved.  Thank you.